# What does ガスッ mean?

Tags: manga, japanese-to-english, sound-symbolism

What does the onomatopoeia that appears in red in the image mean?  I'm not really sure if it says ガヌッ or ガスッ ,since I'm not good at identifying characters, so I'll leave the image (also to give context)
[image]

Comment: It's just a noise produced by bumping heads.

Comment: Not sure if you still check replies, but was it part of a commercially published manga, or in the case of a amateur work, published online somewhere? If so, I suggest including credits (the name of the author, the name of the work, the URL, etc). In general, it's a good practice to quote things with proper credits.

Answer (score 2):

A typical sound that ガスッ describes is the sound made by a solid and rigid but not too heavy thing (like a wood block) bumping against another solid and rigid but not too heavy thing. In this case, I think it describes that one person is bumping against another person a bit too hard, somewhat metaphorically and exaggeratedly. If it was a quick tap or a soft hug, ガスッ wouldn't be adequate.

Answer (score 1):

It says 「ガスッ」。What it literally means is tough to describe, but I would say it's something similar to a rough hug or grasp.